# Opening a CSV file using intent in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to open any CSV from my device's file manager but i am not finding any flutter's support for it.
I have done androidmanifest changes and now CSV files launch my App but i cannot read the File path .
Is this supported yet in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the follows libraries:

https://pub.dev/packages/excel

https://pub.dev/packages/csv

Comment: This doesn't give me answer